# How to format path-to-file with fopen() in C

Tags: c

I am very new to C and programming in general. I am working on a simple program that prompts user for information on some vehicles and with a struct and writes it down to `.txt` file. It compiles fine with no errors, and asks for the information. However, it returns

> 'Error: No such file or directory'

message. `FILE * fpt` is declared with the header files `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, and struct file. The path Ito file was copied and pasted into my IDE after running pwd command. What am I missing? Happy to past all the code onto here if necessary. Thanks for the help! My code looks like this:

```
FILE * fpt; //<-With header files

fpt = fopen("~/Documents/C_Projects/carInfo.txt", "w");

if (fpt==NULL)
{
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What're the permissions on the file and the directory C_Projects? Perhaps it exits, but cannot be written to? Perhaps you do not have permission to create a new file in that directory?

Comment: Why are using the tilde? C FILE doesn't understand that. Either use wordexp or put the full path there.

Comment: Changed the permissions and the path and it worked. Thanks, gents!